# Does Docker execute containers in parallel?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to know if Docker is running containers in parallel across all CPU cores.

I saw in the performance monitor that the CPU cores usage increase when using Docker but not consistently along the cores.

There are 5 containers in total for a 8 Core machine. There are two containers using Node, one of them using Postgres, the other one RabbitMq, and the other one Traefik.

The Node containers use one core each (internally), I'm wondering how these cores are distributed by Docker.

Comment: A container is just a Linux process. If your computer can run processes in parallel, then your containers are also running in parallel...because they are processes.